# How to find measurements of angle CBD?

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

[image]

I got $x + CBD = 110^{o}$. I think I should find measurements of angle CBD, so how to find it? 
Do you have any ideas? Please help me!

Comment: The answer is $30^\circ$.

Comment: How to find x ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

1. $\angle ACB = 180^\circ-(10^\circ+70^\circ)-(60^\circ+20^\circ) = 20^\circ$ and $\angle AEB = 180^\circ-60^\circ-(50^\circ+30^\circ) = 40^\circ$.
2. Draw a line from point $E$ parallel to $AB$, labeling the intersection with $AC$ as a new point $F$ and conclude $\Delta CEF\sim\Delta  ABC$,
   \begin{align}
   \angle CEF &= \angle CBA = 50^\circ+30^\circ = 80^\circ\\
   \angle FEB &= 180^\circ-80^\circ = 100^\circ\\
   \angle AEF &= 100^\circ-40^\circ = 60^\circ\\
   \angle CFE &= CAB = 60^\circ+20^\circ = 80^\circ\\
   \angle EFA &= 180^\circ-80^\circ = 100^\circ
   \end{align}
3. Draw a line $FB$ labeling the intersection with $AE$ as a new point $G$ and conclude $\Delta AFE\cong\Delta  BEF$, 
   \begin{align}  
   \angle AFB &=\angle BEA = 40^\circ\\
   \angle BFE &= \angle AEF = 60^\circ\\
   \angle FGE &= 180^\circ-60^\circ-60^\circ = 60^\circ = \angle AGB\\
   \angle ABG &= 180^\circ-60^\circ-60^\circ = 60^\circ\\
   \end{align}
4. Draw a line $DG$. Since $AD=AB$ (leg of isosceles) and $AG=AB$ (leg of equilateral), conclude $AD = AG$, $\Delta DAG$ is isosceles and
   $$
   \angle ADG =\angle AGD = \frac{180^\circ-20^\circ}2 = 80^\circ.
   $$
5. Since $\angle DGF = 180^\circ-80^\circ-60^\circ = 40^\circ$, conclude $\Delta FDG$ (with two $40^\circ$ angles) is isosceles, so $DF = DG$.
6. With $EF = EG$ (legs of equilateral) and $DE = DE$ (same line segment) conclude $\Delta DEF\cong\Delta  DEG$ by side-side-side rule, $\angle DEF =\angle DEG = x$, and
   $$
   \angle FEG = 60^\circ = x+x\quad\Rightarrow\quad \large\color{blue}{x=30^\circ}.
   $$

Comment: Did you mean $x=30^\circ$ at the end?

Comment: @S.B. Thanks for the correction. I fix the typo.

Comment: After the construction of FE and point G, CG is then the axis of  symmetry. Thus, some of the angles can be found directly.

Comment: Footnote - this interesting question also permits a solution by Sine Rule when using the 3 Isosceles triangles available, although it is no less complex than the solution given.

Comment: @AlphaFSC Footnote, using trigonometry maybe will be the fastest way but I prefer using pure geometry approach in this case.